# getStaticPaths is required for dynamic SSG pages and is missing for the address

Tags: reactjs, axios, next.js

I'm working on online shop project using fake API. All I want to do is to show list of lots in each category. So I have category component and I want it to go to lotsInCategory page(lotsInCategory/[category]/index.tsx) when I click it. But when I click the link in the category page(category.tsx), I see this error:

> Error: getStaticPaths is required for dynamic SSG pages and is missing for '/lotsInCategory/[category]'.

This my folder structure:

[image]

This is category.tsx:

```
import React from 'react'

import Link from 'next/link

const Category = ({lots,category}:{lots:Array<any>,category:string}) => {
  //category is an string passed from another component
 return (
    
    <>
{/* The line below shows me the category is passed currently */}
    {console.log(category)}
    <Link href={{pathname:`/lotsInCategory/${category}`}} as={`/lotsInCategory/${category}`}>
    <div className="category">
      <div className="img-container">
    
    </div>
    <div className="title">
    {category}
    </div>
    </div>
    </Link>
    </>
  )
}
export default Category;
```

And this is the lotsInCategory component(lotsInCategory/[category]/index.tsx):

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import https from "https"
import { GetStaticPaths,GetStaticProps } from 'next';
 const LotsInCategory = ({data}:{data:Array<any>}) => {
  return (<>
{console.log(data)}
    <div>lotsInCategory</div>
</>
  )
}

axios.defaults.httpsAgent=new https.Agent({
  rejectUnauthorized:false,
})

const getStaticPaths:GetStaticPaths=async(context:any)=>{


 
  let paths:Array<any>=[]
  try{
   const response=await axios.get(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products`)
   paths=await response.data.map((el:any)=>({params:{category:el.category.toString()}}))
  
  
  }
  catch(er){
    
  }

  return{
    paths,
    fallback:true
  }

}
export const getStaticProps:GetStaticProps=async(context:any)=>{
  let data:Array<any> =[]
  try{
    const response= await axios.get(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/category/${context.params.category}`)
    data=response.data
    alert("x")
  }
  catch(er:any){

  }
  return{
    props:{data},
    revalidate:2
  }
}
export default LotsInCategory
```

And I don't want to use getServersideProps as possible!

Comment: is it because getstaticPaths shouldn't have a context parameter?

Comment: Tnx. But I don't think so I just removed the context parameter, But I steel have the same error.

Comment: I think it's also missing an export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `export` your `getStaticPaths` function. Also the [getStaticPaths](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths) function does not take any parameters:

> For TypeScript, you can use the GetStaticPaths type from next:

```js
import { GetStaticPaths } from 'next'

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Oh my gosh! Silly me . You're right I missed exporting getStaticPaths! Special tnx @ChristianHagelid.